# Why is the *then* callback not working when calling it after adding a document to firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart

In the initState I am calling a future function `firstLoadTab()`.
firstLoadTab code:

```
Future firstLoadTab() async {
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> query = await todo.get();
if (query.docs.toList().isEmpty) {
  await todo.add({
    'todo': newToDo.task,
    'subTask': newToDo.subTask,
    'isChecked': newToDo.isChecked,
    'date': 'Today'
  }).then((doc) {
    doc.get().then((Doc) {
      context.read<Tabs>().addTabs(Doc['date']);
      context.read<Views>().addView(Container(
            color: Colors.white,
          ));
    });
  });
  ;
}}
```

`todo` is a collection reference.
so I query, or request, the docs and when I do I check if any document exists. If not, I add a document to the collection then I call the callback `then` but doesn't work. **Why????**

Tabs and Views are models.
`initState:`

```
      @override 
void initState() {
    firstLoadTab();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: I have no idea why you got downvoted, but is there as reason you are using `.then()` in the first place? Just use `await` and put breakpoints.

Comment: so 2 awaits in 1 if statement?

Comment: Might even be 3. There is no need to use a `then` here, it only complicates things.

Answer (score 1):

I will restructure your code this way:

```
Future firstLoadTab() async {
//if you want to get Data just from server + if "any" document exists (at least one)
try{
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> query = await todo.limit(1).get(GetOptions(source: Source.server));

if (query.docs.isEmpty) {
Map<String,dynamic> _fields = {
    'todo': newToDo.task,
    'subTask': newToDo.subTask,
    'isChecked': newToDo.isChecked,
    'date': 'Today'
  };
await todo.add(_fields);
context.read<Tabs>().addTabs(_fields['date']);
context.read<Views>().addView(Container(color: Colors.white));
    } 

 } on FirebaseException catch (_){
   print(_); // do something
 } catch(_){
   print(_); // do something
 }
  
}
```

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 116 pos 14: 'path.isNotEmpty': a document path must be a non-empty string
```

This error has nothing to do with the above code. It has to do with what you pass into ```todo``. The error means your document path is empty.

For example you need to do this:

```
var todo = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Todo"); ///then you can use the above code
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but why do i get this exception. ```Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 116 pos 14: 'path.isNotEmpty': a document path must be a non-empty string```